# Java Stop Script Continuation Without System.exit(1);

Tags: java, exception

I have a program and I am catching an error. I need the program to stop and stay idle if there is an exception.

I have this:

```
// Try to parse the integer just to make sure it's an integer.
try {
    Integer.parseInt(celsiusTxtField.getText());
}

// Catch it if it's not an integer and murder the user for being stupid. They should know temperature consists of numbers and not letters.
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not submit a number. Please try again.", "General Error - Error #2", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

But, even though it shows the error message, it still continues on with the script.

This is probably really simple, but I'm new to Java, so please excuse my not knowing.

Comment: @Alex I usually program in PHP and that was force of habit, lol. I fixed it. :), sorry.

Comment: - This is not PHP 
 - Show more code (to see why the script continues.. we need more explanation on your problem

Good luck!

Comment: And show us a little bit more code about your problem

Comment: @JT White - not funny.  Perhaps you'd like to explain why you think it is funny to mistag questions?

Comment: @HulkThor - this is not an answer.  Please delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a way to do this.

Move everything under TRY, and that way, the CATCH is the last thing, so there's nothing else to be executed.